# Vanilla Javascript: counter variable of for loop undefined when used in function

Tags: javascript

This is a Sudoko generator I'm programming in vanilla javascript:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mles/33rfamp2/)

[Nicer looking full screen JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mles/33rfamp2/embedded/result/)

If you click on one of the fields, a popup will be shown with 3x3 fields from 1 to 9. If you click on one of the fields of the popup f. ex. `5`, it should change the parent field to `5`.
The problem is that it changes the parent field to `undefined`.

Here is the relevant code where I generate my popup:

```
    // create popup
    function createPopup(position) {
        var popup = document.createElement('dialog');
        popup.className = 'popup';
        popup.id = 'window_' + position;

        var dialogblock = popup.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
        dialogblock.className = 'popupblock';

        for (var z = 1; z <= 9; z++) {
            var div = dialogblock.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));

            div.className = 'popupcell';
            div.id = position + 'z' + z;
            div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(z));

            div.onclick = function (e, z) {
                document.getElementById(position).innerHTML = z;
                e.stopPropagation();
                popup.close();
            };
        }

        return popup;
    }
```

The problem seems to be that `z` is in another scope when passing it to `div.onclick`. How can I pass `z` to another function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Problem #1

The event handler function assigned to [`GlobalEventHandlers.onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) will only be passed one argument when called.

```
div.onclick = function (e, z)
```

There is no second argument, get rid of `, z` here.

#### Problem #2

Because the onclick function will not be executed until that element receives a click event, you need to wrap the body of your for-loop in an immediately invoked function expression[<sup>1</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)<sup>,</sup>[<sup>2</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) in order to create a new lexical scope for each iteration of the loop.

This makes `z` in the context of your event handler reference the value of `z` in the current iteration of the loop instead the value of `z` at the at the last iteration of the loop.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/33rfamp2/1/)

```js
for (var z = 1; z <= 9; z++) (function(z){

    var div = dialogblock.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));

    div.className = 'popupcell';
    div.id = position + 'z' + z;
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(z));

    div.onclick = function (e) {
        console.log(e, z);
        document.getElementById(position).innerHTML = z;
        e.stopPropagation();
        popup.close();
    };
})(z);
```